# Installing PCL on Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: software-installation

I installed Ubuntu 18.4 as Windows 10 subsystem. And I am trying to install PCL following [this](https://larrylisky.com/2014/03/03/installing-pcl-on-ubuntu/) link.

./RedistMaker build is failing. Please help.

Here are some error messages.

`../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/Device.cpp:251:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int scanf(const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  scanf("%d", &chosen);`

```
In file included from ../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_obs.h:62:0,
               from ../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/NiViewer.cpp:62:
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:115:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
   equivalent(int __i, const error_condition& __cond) const noexcept;
   ^
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:115:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:115:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:115:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:118:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
   equivalent(const error_code& __code, int __i) const noexcept;
   ^
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:118:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:118:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error:118:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/7/system_error: In function ‘bool std::operator==(const std::error_code&, const std::error_condition&)’:
../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_linear.h:80:33: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
#define     equivalent(a,b)     (((a < b + GLH_EPSILON) && (a > b - GLH_EPSILON)) ? true : false)
                               ^
../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_linear.h:80:42: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const std::error_condition’ and ‘float’)
#define     equivalent(a,b)     (((a < b + GLH_EPSILON) && (a > b - GLH_EPSILON)) ? true : false)
../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_linear.h:80:42: note: candidate: operator+(int, float) <built-in>
../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_linear.h:80:42: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::error_condition’ to ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
               from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:61,
               from ../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_glut2.h:51,
               from ../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/NiViewer.cpp:63:`

Another one 
`../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_linear.h:80:67: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘const std::error_condition’ and ‘float’)
#define     equivalent(a,b)     (((a < b + GLH_EPSILON) && (a > b - GLH_EPSILON)) ? true : false)
../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_linear.h:80:67: note: candidate: operator-(int, float) <built-in>
../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_linear.h:80:67: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::error_condition’ to ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
               from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:61,
               from ../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/glh/glh_glut2.h:51,
               from ../../../../../Samples/NiViewer/NiViewer.cpp:63:`

`make[1]: *** [x64-Release/NiViewer.o] Error 1
make: *** [Samples/NiViewer] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Note: ../../../../../Samples/UserTracker.java/org/openni/Samples/UserTracker/UserTracker.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
failed to execute: make  -j16 -C /home/shukhrat/kinect/OpenNI/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/../Build > /home/shukhrat/kinect/OpenNI/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/Output/BuildOpenNI.txt
Building Failed!`
```

Comment: Did you follow all steps? or get any error/warning/unusual messages on any steps?  If so you should provide these if you expect us to help.  Builds usually provide lots of messages which contain the needed clues & even solutions as to what is required (ie. what is missing, what needs installing)

Comment: @guiverc, thanks for your reply. Yes I followed all the steps. I had a problem with installing libvtk5.8-qt4 libvtk5.8 libvtk5-dev only, I solved it by installing libvtk7.  I will add error message in my question.

Comment: Since you substituted a library - did you confirm there are no API changes?

Comment: How do you confirm, should you check that? Sorry I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: You are dealing with open-source; and compiling (the build step), so you look at the source code and diff/compare the calls to ensure there is no change (esp. significant that will create segfaults). You've jumped from 5 to 7, whilst each team can follow their own rules, major release numbers (eg. 5 to 7, as apart from minor 5 to 5.1) can mean change to API/ABI's which are the reason for package rules. Since you're ignoring the rules, you have to ensure the breaching of rules is okay. Programmers can't know the future, so some rules are just for 'safety' but also may be planned change.